# Enity Data source wizard only compatiible with framework 5

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I'm going to try and connect to my EF Data Model for the first time and when I do I pull this error message:

> This version of the Entity Data Source wizard is only compatible with Entity Framework 5. If you’re not using Entity Framework 5 you can configure the control by editing the markup on the page. The page editor has IntelliSense support for ASP.NET controls. If you’re using Entity Framework 6 you should also be using the EF6-compatible version of the Entity Data Source control, available as the Microsoft.AspNetEntityDataSource package in NuGet.

Now this threw me a bit because I thought that I had all my updates in place but I went back to NuGet and double checked and did a full refresh of anything I could to make sure that VS knew it was there an verified everything was in place and on 6 as intended.  Then I noted in the update tab there was three items there that I could put up (Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha2, Microsoft.AspNet.Idntity.EntityFramwork v3.0.0-rc1-final, and Microsoft.NetCompliers v1.2.0-rc). This I attempted but that bombs out with the error:

> Failed to add reference to 'System.Runtime'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.

I'm a bit stumped here... no path forward no path backward that I can see.

Comment: I don't think EntityDataSourceControl will work with EF 1 Core / EF7 at all. Up to EF5 you have the wizard, with EF6 you can modify the markup to make EDSC work for EF Core you don't use EDSC. (Microsoft.AspNet.Idntity.EntityFramework v3.0.0-rc1-final is to be used in the new ASP.NET Core thing)

Comment: I'm coming at it blind here as a first time user of EF so what would you recommend? My intent was to be on 6.  Do I need to do something to roll back to 5? The project is almost completed and I don't want to have to rip out a lot of code.

Comment: I would recommend sticking to EF6 right now (i.e. you should not use any Microsoft.AspNet* packages). I would also recommend avoiding EDSC if you can. AFAIR remember it had a number of issues. Maybe you should look at MVC instead of WebForms?